# Merging the Strings

Tags: javascript

HI , 
   In Java Script ,

var a ="apple-orange-mango"
   var b ="grapes-cheery-apple"

var c  = a + b  // Merging with 2 variable

var c should have value is "apple-orange-mango-grapes-cheery" .Duplicated should be removed.

Thanks ,
Chells

Comment: No.. Its issues i faced relove one issue

Comment: it doesn't matter if this is homework or not, it's a nice question that could be reflected on real-life applications, and might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brute force algorithm:

```
var a;
var b; // inputs

var words = split(a+b);
var map = {};
var output;
for( index in words ) {
    if( map[ words[index] ]!=undefined ) continue;
    map[ words[index] ] = true;
    output += (words[index] + '-');
}
output[output.length-1]=' '; // remove the last '-'
```

The `map` acts as a hashtable.

Thats it!

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var a = "s-d-g";
var b = "c-d-s";
var c = a + "-" + b
var Splitted = c.split("-");
var words = Splitted
var map = {};
var output="";
for( index in words ) {
    if( map[ words[index] ]!=undefined ) continue;
    map[ words[index] ] = true;
    if ( output == "") {
       output = words[index];
    } else  { 
       output += ('-'+words[index]);
    }
 
}
output[output.length-1]=' '; 
alert(output) ;

</script>

Comment: Shouldn't we be encouraging people to learn instead of purely posting the answer, especially to such a simple problem.

Comment: @gonzohunter You are right, but this forum here is for programming, not encouragement. So I justify my actions :)

Comment: I just slove some of other issues of using this . It not like simple problem . Its seriouly i need to for some cirtical systems

Answer (score 2):

After your string is combined, you will want to split it using the delimiters (you can add these back in later).

example:

```
var a ="apple-orange-mango" 
var b ="grapes-cheery-apple"
var c = a + "-" + b
var Splitted = c.split("-");
```

the Splitted variable now contains an array such as [apples,orange,mango,grapes,cherry,apple]

you can then use one of many [duplicate removing algorithms](http://www.martienus.com/code/javascript-remove-duplicates-from-array.html) to remove the duplicates. Then you can simply do this to add your delimiters back in:

```
result = Splitted.join("-");
```

Comment: you'd need to include an additional "-" when concatenating between the strings in this particular example.
eg
<code>
var a ="apple-orange-mango" 
var b ="grapes-cheery-apple"
var c = a + "-" + b
</code>

Comment: @both of you....that is copied from OP's code, moreso their mistake. But good eye. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is an homework.

By the way you can split strings like a and b with the split method of string object.
in your case:

```
firstArray=a.split("-");
secondArray=b.split("-");
```

the removal of duplicates is up to you...

Answer (score 1):

In your simple example, just use var c = a + "-" + b;
If you want duplicates removed, split a and b into arrays, and combine them, like so:

```
var avalues = a.split("-");
var bvalues = b.split("-");
var combined = avalues.concat( bvalues );
// now loop over combined and remove duplicates
```